# How to disable solr admin page

Tags: solr

For production, it feels unsafe to have a solr admin which even doesn't ask login credentials. How can I disable the solr admin page which comes by default? I simply want my webapp to use Solr for search term indexing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I highly suggest keeping the admin page for debugging purposes. It has saved me in numerous cases. There are ways to restrict it to HTTP-authenticated users only: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity#Jetty_example . You may have to unzip and re-zip your webapp.

However if you still want to disable the entire admin section, you can comment out the admin requestHandler in ${SOLR_HOME}/project/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml .

Answer (score 3):

You could protect your admin page with a password just by adding a security constraint to the Solr web application.

Snippet for Solr 3.6:

```
  <security-constraint>
    <!-- This protects your admin interface and grants access to role Solr-Admin -->
    <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Solr admin</web-resource-name>
      <!--url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern-->
      <url-pattern>/evu/admin/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/webcrawl/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>Solr-Admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <security-constraint>
    <!-- This protects your admin interface and grants access to roles Solr-Admin and Solr-Updater -->
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Solr Update</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/update/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/evu/update/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/webcrawl/update/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>Solr-Admin</role-name>
      <role-name>Solr-Update</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <security-constraint>
    <!-- This one is necessary to show the image on the Solr start page -->
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Solr Admin images</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-contraint>
      <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-contraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <security-role>
    <description>The role that is required to administer Solr</description>
    <role-name>Solr-Admin</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <description>The role that is required to update the Solr index</description>
    <role-name>Solr-Update</role-name>
  </security-role>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Solr</realm-name>
  </login-config>
</web-app>
```

In Solr 4 you have to protect the following resources for the admin interface:

```
/admin/*
/admin.html
```

Comment: In what file to add this snippet?

Comment: That would be web.xml. I am not sure about the jetty configuration.

Answer (score 0):

sudo vim /opt/solr-4.8.1/example/etc/jetty.xml
change

```
  <!-- This connector is currently being used for Solr because it
          showed better performance than nio.SelectChannelConnector
          for typical Solr requests.  -->
    <Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
            <Set name="host">0.0.0.0</Set>
            <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8983"/></Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">50000</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourceMaxIdleTime">1500</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
          </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
```

to

```
 <!-- This connector is currently being used for Solr because it
          showed better performance than nio.SelectChannelConnector
          for typical Solr requests.  -->
    <Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
            <Set name="host">127.0.0.1</Set>
            <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8983"/></Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">50000</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourceMaxIdleTime">1500</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
          </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
```

then
     sudo service solrd restart

Answer (score -3):

The most easy way:

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8983 -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1 --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT

with this order!

Comment: When I tried this,my site scripts could no longer access Solr - I played around a bit with iptables trying different ip addresses and other things to no avail (perhaps due to my lack of expert knowledge on this).
I'm still looking for the easy answer with no luck do far...

Comment: Because wrong order. Here oneliner: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT && iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8983 -j DROP && iptables-save > iptables.rules && iptables-restore < iptables.rules && rm iptables.rules`