# Start Apache Solr without Admin UI?

Tags: solr

Is there a way to disable the web UI of Apache Solr? I would like to expose the Rest API only without users being able to access the web UI, without or without authentication?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776263/how-to-disable-solr-admin-page

Comment: The Admin UI is just a Javascript application that uses the underlying REST API for any operation, so even if you remove the files (i.e. no interface gets served), a user could in theory just run a copy of the application locally to access the same endpoints (.. or any other client). You might want to use [proper authentication and authorization instead](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/rule-based-authorization-plugin.html#rule-based-authorization-plugin). You can add a custom rule with the `/admin` endpoint as its path.

Comment: @MatsLindh this makes me believe I can develop my own JS application correct ?

Comment: That is correct. As long as you solve any cross site origin issues, either by serving the content from the Solr host/port combination, by proxying the requests to Solr or by making Solr append a origin header to allow connections from a different host.

Comment: Well I plan to create a desktop application of it and I don't want tons of processes to run locally so I am trying to replace the original interface :D